# TRegistry::KeyExists() fails when key has spaces

Tags: registry, c++builder

Consider the following:

```
TRegistry* registry = new TRegistry();
registry->RootKey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
registry->Access  = KEY_READ;

if (true == registry->KeyExists("Software\\Abc\\My Key")) // note the space
{
   // read
}
else
{
   // error 
}
```

The above case is going into `else` block. I guess the issue is because of the space present in the key. Or is it something else? Note that I am able to read `"Software\\Abc"` successfully.

I already tried using double quotes, like this:

```
if (true == registry->KeyExists("\"Software\\Abc\\My Key\""))
{
    ....
}
```

but all in vain.

Any leads?

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is perfectly fine and correct.  You do not need to put extra quotes around strings with spaces in them.  Registry key names can have spaces in them, and if you actually look in the Registry you will actually see keys *all over the place* that have spaces in them.

`KeyExists()` tests for existence by actually opening the specified key and then closing it.  When `KeyExists()` returns false, it means `TRegistry` was not able to open the specified key.

`KeyExists()` ignores the current `Access` property value (other than to use any specified `KEY_WOW64` flag).  It uses its own `Access` flags, specifically `STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ`, `KEY_QUERY_VALUE`, and `KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS`.  So, when `KeyExists()` returns false, either the key really does not exist, or more likely the calling thread does not have security rights to open the key with those permissions (which is not unheard of when accessing keys in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`).

Unfortunately, `KeyExists()` does not update the `TRegistry::LastError` property (if you are using a version of C++Builder that has that property available), so you can't differentiate why `KeyExists()` is returning false.

If you want to check if the target key exists without actually opening the key itself, one way would be to open the parent key first and then call `GetKeyNames()` to get a list of its subkeys, then see if your target key is in the list.  Of course, this requires having security access to the parent key.

Since `KeyExists()` actually opens the key, another way would be to simply open the key yourself (especially if you are planning on actually reading values from the key).  Use `OpenKeyReadOnly()` for that, eg:

```cpp
TRegistry* registry = new TRegistry();
registry->RootKey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;

// only if needed:
registry->Access = KEY_WOW64_32KEY; // or KEY_WOW64_64KEY

if (registry->OpenKeyReadOnly("Software\\Abc\\My Key"))
{
   // read...

   registry->CloseKey();
}
else
{
   // error 
}
```

The benefits of doing this are that:

1. `OpenKeyReadOnly()` (and `OpenKey()`) updates the `LastError` property.
2. `OpenKeyReadOnly()` attempts several different combinations of `Access` flags to have a better chance of actually opening the key for reading.  While taking WOW64 into account, it:

   1. first attempts `KEY_READ`, which is a combination of `STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ`, `KEY_QUERY_VALUE`, `KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS`, and `KEY_NOTIFY`, minus `SYNCHORNIZE`.
   2. If that fails, it then attempts `STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ`, `KEY_QUERY_VALUE`, and `KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS` (same as `KeyExists()`).
   3. If that fails, it then attempts `KEY_QUERY_VALUE` by itself.  If the key actually exists, this will usually succeed, unless a security policy is in place to explicitly deny reading access.
   4. If that fails, it gives up.

Like anything else in Windows security, you should strive to request only the bare minimum permissions that you actually need, no more than that.  For example, if you need to read values in the key, but don't need to access subkeys, you could alternatively do this instead:

```cpp
TRegistry* registry = new TRegistry();
registry->RootKey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
registry->Access = KEY_QUERY_VALUE; // and KEY_WOW64_32KEY/KEY_WOW64_64KEY if needed

if (registry->OpenKey("Software\\Abc\\My Key", false))
{
   // read...

   registry->CloseKey();
}
else
{
   // error 
}
```

Though typically you should stick with `OpenKeyReadOnly()` when you need reading access, unless you absolutely need more control over the `Access` flags, then use `OpenKey()` instead.